# Remove light effect (without changing foreground)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

It's about the following image: https://vsthemes.org/en/wallpapers/games/35866-assassins-creed-origins-egyptian-hi.html

I would like to adjust this as follows:

- The light beam on the top right of the image should be gone, so that the whole background looks the same / is the same dark as the left part of the image. At the same time the hieroglyphs should not be lightened / darkened but only the background.
- On the right side all hieroglyphs are dark, these should also be supplemented with bright golden hieroglyphs

How would you proceed here?
Are there any tutorials you can recommend?

Since I am not yet so versed in Photoshop it would be mega great if you could give me a step by step instructions!

Thanks a lot for your input!
Greetings
Silvan

Comment: Overall.. it would be less work and faster to just recreate the image from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I removed my comment and wrote the same as an answer. I wouldn't try to fix your image. It would take maybe 100 hours to make perfect enough selections or layer masks to do it. I would draw a new image. If some non-western writing with an available font would do the wanted effect I would use it. If only hieroglyphs go, I would try to get them.

There are some hieroglyph translator websites which allow you to write your own hieroglyphic texts. I copied some from here https://lingojam.com/HieroglyphicsTranslator (see NOTE1)

[image]

They are only a screenshot pasted to Photoshop, the white BG is deleted and the items are moved to a tighter formation. Not a slightest idea are they placed obeying any writing rules nor does this mean something.

They are used to make the next image:

[image]

The base plate layer has grooves which are actually a quite complex horizontal gradient. It's colors are copied from your image. You may want grooves with sharper edges. An easy way to get it is to make it by extruding the groove profile in Illustrator and adjusting the lights.

On the top there's a noise texture layer. That's optional but it should present the wanted material surface. I guess a stone plate photo would be ideal, but I haven't one. This is solid grey with noise, blurred and embossed, it has blending mode Hard Light and low opacity.

The hieroglyphs are used to make a selection which is used to delete parts of the noise and base plate layers (= make holes).

Layer style Bevel&Emboss is applied to the base plate to generate apparent slopes to the holes. The settings of the layer style are shown.

In the background there's the "gold". A photo of real gold would be the best. This is only some yellow which got a litlle blurred and embossed noise. The contrast is increased to make the "gold" not perfectly uniform. The yellow is used as the light of the Bevel&Emboss Effect.

The layers are moved apart in the next image. The noise layer is turned to 100% opacity. It looks quite the same as the sandstone texture filter would give in Photoshop with no effort. The base plate is shown without Bevel&Emboss layer style.

[image]

**NOTE1**: At least Google Fabricius gives its hieroglyphs as vectors when one exports the text writing page as PDF. They can be extracted in Illustrator. The whole job (without too detailed surface textures)can be then done as a vector drawing in Illustrator.

**A warning:** before you copy hieroglyphs from somewhere, check their licensing. It's well possible that the hieroglyphs are actually copyrighted drawings of someone who do not allow using them as a part of arts or items for sale for free. If he doesn't want money he may want his name to be shown. So, check the license!

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer! Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Curves layer adjustment, then paint on a black filled mask in white or grey, with a large soft edged brush to tone down the light reflection in the required areas.

Example

[image]Click to see larger

Comment: Hi Billy Kerr, this looks interesting. Sorry but would it be possible to explain in a little more detail how i can achieve this result? It looks quite interesting.... Could you maybe give me a step by step instruction?

Comment: @Silvan - This is fairly basic stuff to be honest. You add a Curves layer adjustment, create a S curve as shown, select the mask in the layers panel, fill it all black, then paint on it with a brush.  Not sure how much simpler I could make it for you.

Comment: @Silvan if you are looking for step by step tutorials, youtube is a good source. Maybe look up tutorials on adjustment layers, and masking if you are unfamiliar with these methods. These are kind of the bread and butter of making fine adjustments to lighting in Photoshop.

Comment: @Silvan - found a good one for you here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2E-KOAmhuA - and another: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mEjNGh9N5A

Comment: @Silvan and this one is a little more advanced. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puz8TJ8axLU

Comment: Many thanks for your support!